# Modelo Entity Recognizer (NLP) falla en algunas ocasiones

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

He creado un modelo NER con Spacy, el cual ha sido entrenado con un conjunto de 10000 oraciones (en total, hay 33 oraciones para cada una de las etiquetas que el modelo debe ser capaz de reconocer en un texto dado. Además, los oraciones se repiten, en un intento de que el modelo tenga más datos con los que poder entrenarse).

La estructura de los datos de entrenamiento del modelo es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El modelo ha sido creado de la siguiente manera:

```
!pip install spacy
!python3 -m spacy download es_core_news_sm
import es_core_news_sm
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin

nlp = es_core_news_sm.load() # load other spacy model

db_train = DocBin() # create a DocBin object


for text, annot in tqdm(train): # data in previous format
    doc = nlp.make_doc(text) # create doc object from text
    ents = []
    for start, end, label in annot["entities"]: # add character indexes
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label, alignment_mode="contract")
        if span is None:
            pass
        else:
            ents.append(span)
    doc.ents = ents # label the text with the ents
    db_train.add(doc)


db_train.to_disk("./train.spacy") # save the docbin object



# ----------------------------

db_test = DocBin() # create a DocBin object


for text, annot in tqdm(test): # data in previous format
    doc = nlp.make_doc(text) # create doc object from text
    ents = []
    for start, end, label in annot["entities"]: # add character indexes
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label, alignment_mode="contract")
        if span is None:
            pass
        else:
            ents.append(span)
    doc.ents = ents # label the text with the ents
    db_test.add(doc)


db_test.to_disk("./test.spacy") # save the docbin object
```

---

**CONFIGURACION MODELO**

Luego, en la web de Spacy, he generado un archivo de configuración propio para el modelo NER que quiero crear. El archivo base_config.cfg tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
# This is an auto-generated partial config. To use it with 'spacy train'
# you can run spacy init fill-config to auto-fill all default settings:
# python -m spacy init fill-config ./base_config.cfg ./config.cfg
[paths]
train = null
dev = null
vectors = "es_core_news_sm"
[system]
gpu_allocator = null

[nlp]
lang = "es"
pipeline = ["tok2vec","ner"]
batch_size = 1000

[components]

[components.tok2vec]
factory = "tok2vec"

[components.tok2vec.model]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2Vec.v2"

[components.tok2vec.model.embed]
@architectures = "spacy.MultiHashEmbed.v2"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
attrs = ["NORM", "PREFIX", "SUFFIX", "SHAPE"]
rows = [5000, 1000, 2500, 2500]
include_static_vectors = true

[components.tok2vec.model.encode]
@architectures = "spacy.MaxoutWindowEncoder.v2"
width = 256
depth = 8
window_size = 1
maxout_pieces = 3

[components.ner]
factory = "ner"

[components.ner.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v2"
state_type = "ner"
extra_state_tokens = false
hidden_width = 64
maxout_pieces = 2
use_upper = true
nO = null

[components.ner.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}

[corpora]

[corpora.train]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.train}
max_length = 0

[corpora.dev]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.dev}
max_length = 0

[training]
dev_corpus = "corpora.dev"
train_corpus = "corpora.train"

[training.optimizer]
@optimizers = "Adam.v1"

[training.batcher]
@batchers = "spacy.batch_by_words.v1"
discard_oversize = false
tolerance = 0.2

[training.batcher.size]
@schedules = "compounding.v1"
start = 100
stop = 1000
compound = 1.001

[initialize]
vectors = ${paths.vectors}
```

En el cuaderno que utilizo para desarrollar el modelo, ejecuto la instrucción:

```
!python -m spacy init fill-config base_config.cfg config.cfg
```

Esto me generará un archivo de configuración a partir del archivo que acabo de obtener de la web de Spacy.

---

**ENTRENAMIENTO MODELO**

Por último, entreno el modelo con la instrucción:

```
!python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./output --paths.train ./train.spacy --paths.dev ./test.spacy
```

---

**RESULTADOS MODELO**

Una vez entrenado el modelo, escribo una oración de ejemplo:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
import es_core_news_sm

solicitud = """muchas graciaas por las resistencias. Me gustaria que me enviarais una tuerca.
Ah! Quisiera pedir también, un motor para mi coche. Y un reteneDOR. Y unas memorias RAM. Y unas LEDs."""

frasesSolicitud = sent_tokenize(solicitud)


frasesProcesadas = []
nlp = es_core_news_sm.load()

for frase in frasesSolicitud:
    frasesSinVerbos = []
    texto = frase.lower()
    texto = texto.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    
    doc = nlp(texto)
    #print(doc)
    for palabra in doc:
        #print(palabra, palabra.pos_)
        if palabra.pos_ != 'VERB' and palabra.pos_ != 'PRON':
            frasesSinVerbos.append(str(palabra))
    else:
        #print(frasesSinVerbos)
        textoSinVerbos = ' '.join(frasesSinVerbos)
        frasesProcesadas.append(textoSinVerbos)


productosReconocidos = []

nlp1 = spacy.load("./output/model-best")  # Carga el mejor modelo

for item in frasesProcesadas:
    fraseProcesada = item.lower()
    doc = nlp1(fraseProcesada)

    spacy.displacy.render(doc, style="ent", jupyter=True)
        # Extraer las etiquetas de las entidades nombradas detectadas
    for item in doc.ents:
        productosReconocidos.append(item.label_)
    
print(productosReconocidos)
```

La salida que me ofrece el modelo es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, ha **reconocido correctamente todas las etiquetas**.

Sin embargo, hay ocasiones en las que **se reconoce una etiqueta de forma incorrecta**. Me gustaría saber porqué ocurre esto, y como poder solucionarlo. En el entrenamiento del modelo, la Pipeline me mostraba los siguientes valores para diferentes métricas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**EJEMPLO ERROR**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por el momento, incluso si tu modelo lo hubiera hecho el propio openai, tendrá falsos positivos o falsos negativos y, al final de cuentas, un ser humano tendrá que revisar el resultado. Supongo que lo mejor es que entrenes a la ia de tal manera que haya menos falsos positivos, pero no podrás reducirlos al punto de que no meresca revisión humana.